# Programs to model a 3D head

Tags: animation, 3d

I am doing a project where I have to make a 3D head which I have to animate to show a range of expressions.

All I wanted to know is your opinion of the best software(preferably free) that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

[Blender](http://www.blender.org/), though it can be a little difficult to get used to, is powerful, well documented, lots of tutorials (I used [these](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozlwcQT-U20)), and is [completely free](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wHnFYMHrFE&feature=player_detailpage#t=236s).